# github action: run a test file on pull request

Tags: github, mocha.js, github-actions

I want to run a test file when someone sends a pull request.
This is my `action.yml` file.

```
name: "GitHub Actions Test"
on:
    pull_request:
        branches:
            - master


jobs:
    test:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            # - uses: actions/checkout@v1
            - name: 'Install Node'
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
            - name: Install mocha
              run: npm install -g mocha
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: npm install 
            - name: "Run Test"
              run: mocha test-mocha.test.js
```

but when running the test from github, I got the following error:

`Error: No test files found: "test-mocha.test.js"`

I wonder something is wrong on the last line of my yml file. 
how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you've commented out the line that checks out your code:

```yaml
# - uses: actions/checkout@v1 # Remove the comment from this line
```

By default, your code is not checked out in the workflow's directory. As such, you have to use the [Checkout GitHub Action](https://github.com/actions/checkout) to check out your code.

From the README:

> This action checks-out your repository under `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE`, so your workflow can access it.

Comment: I removed the line
but it says,
`You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 12`

This is my acton.yml
https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/224e6db55cca59548c073b620c14e394

Comment: You're missing the hyphen from the step that indicates that it's a separate object.